# Check if part of an object contains another entire object

Tags: javascript

I have a large object that is dynamic but it has a simple structure like below:

```
let numbers = {
    one:   true,
    two:   false,
    three: false,
    four:  true,
    five:  true,
    six:   false,
    seven: false,
    eight: false,
    nine:  false,
    ten:   false
};
```

and then an array of smaller object which are dynamic and could or could not contain values from the first object.

```
let input = [{ one: true, four: true, five: true}, { one: true, two: true, three: true, ten: true}];
```

So what I need is to see if all of the properties in the second object exactly match the corresponding properties in the first object. In the case above the first object would be a match but the second would fail since `ten: true` does not match the corresponding property in the first object.

This is what I've come up with but it seems very inefficient and I can't help but think there's a better way:

```
checkMatch(numbers, input) {

    for (let obj of input) {
        let count = 0;

        for (let key of obj) {
            if (numbers[key]) count++;
        }

        if (count == Object.keys(obj).length) console.log('match');
        else console.log('no match');
    }

}
```

Comment: One way or another you're going to have to iterate through the array and through each property of its contents.

Comment: Have yo checked https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isMatch?

Comment: @SandipNirmal Lodash might make the code more compact but it must inevitably do the same work.

Comment: @Pointy Yes that is for sure, but anyways we have to make iterations to make this work. It's better to use ``loadsh`` since this is already tested across browser and node.

Comment: @SandipNirmal Lodash is a good suggestion but I don't need any other functionality from it in my application so it doesn't seem like a good fit.

Comment: Okay, even I try to avoid using ``lodash`` if things are possible with JavaScript methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array#every()` on `Object.entries()`

```js
let numbers = {
    one:   true,
    two:   false,
    three: false,
    four:  true,
    five:  true,
    six:   false,
    seven: false,
    eight: false,
    nine:  false,
    ten:   false
};

let input = [{ one: true, four: true, five: true}, { one: true, two: true, three: true, ten: true}];

input.forEach(o=>{
   const isMatch = Object.entries(o).every(arr=> numbers[arr[0]] == arr[1])
   console.log( [isMatch,o] );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the entries and check if the original object contains the property and the value.

```js
const
    check = o => Object.entries(o).every(([k, v]) => k in numbers && numbers[k] === v),
    numbers = { one: true, two: false, three: false, four: true, five: true, six: false, seven: false, eight: false, nine: false, ten: false },
    input = [{ one: true, four: true, five: true }, { one: true, two: true, three: true, ten: true }];

console.log(input.map(check));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate and check for the keys using [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) you can match all

```js
let input = [{
  one: true,
  four: true,
  five: true
}, {
  one: true,
  two: true,
  three: true,
  ten: true
}];
let numbers = {
  one: true,
  two: false,
  three: false,
  four: true,
  five: true,
  six: false,
  seven: false,
  eight: false,
  nine: false,
  ten: false
};



input.forEach(a => {
  var matches = Object.keys(a).every(b => numbers[b] === a[b]);
  console.log(matches);
})
```

Comment: You can use `.every` instead of `.map` and therefore not need the `matches` flag.

Comment: Can probably also just do: `Object.keys(a).every(b => numbers[b] === a[b])`